# How to update the UI element of a Class A ie (UIViewController) from another class B ie (UIVIew)

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, user-interface

I am trying to change the Background color of class A from class B which is `View-Controller` and View type class but I am not able to do this.

I know there is something i have to do with threading.
I have tried using `performSelectorOnMainThread` method and few more but nothing is working for me.

my code is given below-

```
//  In Class B
-(void)method{
 ClassAViewController *AView=[[ClassAViewController alloc]init];
    AView.imageIndex=self.currentRenderingImageIndex;
    [AView findIndexOfImage];
}
```

Now i am calling Class A method

```
-(void)findIndexOfImage
{
   NSLog(@"print the index is %i",imageIndex);// This is working fine
   AView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];// Here it is not updating my view.

}
```

I know this is very silly question i asked here, please tell me what should i do.

Comment: use self.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

Answer (score 0):

Simply call these lines from class B:

```
BaseViewController *objBaseViewController = [[BaseViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BaseViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [objBaseViewController firstlink];
```

BaseViewController is my class name you give here your class name & firstlink is my method of class A. so you give here your class A method that you want to call.

Comment: Also in .m of class B import class A .h file like: #import "BaseViewController.h"